# Is there any difference between "sideways" and "to the side"?

Tags: difference, adverbs, phrases

Is there any difference between *sideways* and *to the side*? For example:

> Stop leaning **sideways**/**to the side**!
>
> The car in front of us suddenly moved **sideways**/**to the side**.

I feel that in the examples above *sideways* and to *the side* are interchangeble, I am not sure though. Could you give some examples where only one of the phrases is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever seen a dog try to carry a long stick *sideways* through a narrow gate? That is, the dog holds the stick horizontally (rather than, say, dragging it lengthwise).  Here, “to the side” would not be meaningful.

If a car moves “to the side”, we infer the nearest side of the road.
But in your first example I think “to the side” is less good than “to one side”, because there's no pre-specified or preferred side.

Comment: Hm. I wrote that? It has room for improvement.